# Single Tap to MKMapView without breaking double tap zoom

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to drop a pin on my `MKMapView` when the user single taps on the map. I have the pin code working, I have the single tap working, but when I double tap to zoom I get a single tap first. Here's my code to get the recognizers setup:

```
    self.doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    self.doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    self.doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [mapView_ addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap_];

    self.singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    self.singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTap_];
    [mapView_ addGestureRecognizer:singleTap_];
```

Now, this is not surprising, to quote Apple:

> Note: In the case of the single-tap versus double-tap gestures, if a
>   single-tap gesture recognizer doesn’t require the double-tap
>   recognizer to fail, you should expect to receive your single-tap
>   actions before your double-tap actions, even in the case of a double
>   tap. This is expected and desirable behavior because the best user
>   experience generally involves stackable actions.

So I added `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` to my single tap recognizer.

> [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTap];

and this ensures that my single tap recognizer doesn't get double taps.

But...

Now my double tap recognizer gets the double taps and `MKMapView` doesn't get them. I've tried setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` in the recognizer, but that didn't help either.

So I need a way to either prevent my single tap recognizer from getting double taps (which seems unlikely) or to get my double tap event to my mapView.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to add the gesture recognizers?  Which iOS version are you testing with?  Have you tried returning YES from the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer delegate method?

Comment: question edited to have more code. I'm testing with iOS5.1. Haven't tried the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer delegate, I'll do that now.

Comment: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer=YES did the trick, Make that an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted seems to work fine as-is in iOS 6.
The double-tap is handled automatically by the map view without interfering with the single-tap.

In iOS 5.x, to get the map view to execute its normal double-tap handling without interfering with your single-tap, implement the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` delegate method and return `YES` from it (need to set the `delegate` property of the double-tap gesture recognizer only).

Not sure why this is not necessary in iOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

Working Perfectly on iOS 8, double tap action is null

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTap];
        [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
     }

   - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
     {
            if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
                return;
            //Do your work ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](http://www.mohiji.org/2011/12/15/tracking-touches-in-an-mkmapview/) that helped me quite a lot...
Basically, you need to find Apple's gesture recognizer, and make sure you don't compete with it.

Jonathan's solution was almost perfect, except one thing:
Since in iOS 7 MKView has all it's gestures in a subview. It's kinda convenient if you want to distinguish which are yours (added to the MKMap directly) and which are Apple's, but it might break somewhere in the future....

What I ended up doing was to go over all the map's subview, hoping it'll be flexible enough to withstand at least some future changes...

Looks something like this:

```
- (void) hackInTheGestureRecognizer {

    for (UIView *aSubview in [[self theMap] subviews]) {

        if ([aSubview isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

            for (UIGestureRecognizer *aRecognizer in [aSubview gestureRecognizers]) {

                if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

                    if ([(UITapGestureRecognizer *) aRecognizer numberOfTapsRequired] == 2) {

                        [[self singleTapRecognizer] requireGestureRecognizerToFail:aRecognizer];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version on iOS 10:

```
// Gesture recognizer set up in Interface Builder
@IBOutlet weak var singleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // double tap recognizer has no action
    let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)

    singleTapRecognizer.require(toFail: doubleTapRecognizer)
}
```

Note that the single tap is created in IB. It could easily be created in code like so:

```
    let singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("someAction"))
    singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer)
```